# Why are we getting this error? The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden when calling the google api

Tags: google-api

Why are we getting this error? The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden when calling the google api.  We have been using this for certain times, but now get this error. Here is our code:

```
try
{
            NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
            data.Add("accountType", "GOOGLE");
            data.Add("Email", Settings.Default.AnalyticsAdmin);

            data.Add("Passwd", Settings.Default.AnalyticsAdminCredentials);
            data.Add("service", "analytics");
            data.Add("source", this.GetType().FullName);

            //xml = this.GetType().FullName + ":" + Settings.Default.AnalyticsAdmin + ":" + Settings.Default.AnalyticsAdminCredentials;

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                String tokens = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(client.UploadValues(https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin, "POST", data));
            }
```